# Why does one of my web pages always open twice in Chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome

I've got a website with one main page which contains a link to a secondary one showing account details when a user logs in. In Chrome, when a user opens the secondary page, it always appears duplicated, in two tabs. The problem does not occur in IE or Firefox. Why could this be? I'm wondering if it might be something to do with my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^server2\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?template=error404 [L,QSA]
```

I note that, for every page I load in Chrome, the following errors appear on my error log on my hosting platform:

> [03-Dec-2019 10:30:11 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> [03-Dec-2019 10:30:11 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Module 'SourceGuardian' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Maybe this has something to do with it?

Thanks

Comment: Here's the html for opening the page, nothing unusual:       <a href="account.php"><div class="userLogin tooltip" title="Your account">  <!--Why does the account page appear twice in Chrome?   -->
        <img src="images/icons/user.png" alt="" class="iconUser">
       </div></a>. I've tried removing the htaccess file and substituting a very basic html page for account.php, neither prevents this problem.